# Why does my game character keep accelerating when I use the keydown event?

Tags: javascript, game-physics

I am trying to make a simple game. The green block is my game character. I used a the keydown event to make my character able to move right and left. When I hold down the right or left arrow key, the character keeps on accelerating. If you start by tapping the right or left arrow key, you will see that the space interval between where the character was and where it is increases as you click more. How can I make my character move at a constant speed with constant space intervals.

```js
//variables
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var draw = canvas.getContext("2d");
var characterx = 20;
var charactery = window.innerHeight - 60;
var dx = 0.01;
var dy = 0.01;

//canvas size
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;



//main game function
function run() {

 //loops the function
 requestAnimationFrame(run);

 //clears the screen
 draw.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

 //draws the ground
 draw.beginPath();
 draw.fillStyle = "#823819";
 draw.fillRect(0, canvas.height - 20, canvas.width, 20);
 draw.fill();
 draw.closePath();

 //draws the main character
 draw.beginPath();
 draw.fillStyle = "#128522";
 draw.fillRect(characterx, charactery, 40, 40);
 draw.fill();
 draw.closePath();

 //key evevnts
 window.addEventListener("keydown",function(event) {
  if(event.keyCode == 39) {
   characterx  += dx;
  }
 });

 window.addEventListener("keydown",function(event) {
  if(event.keyCode == 37) {
   characterx  -= dx;
  }  
 });

};
run();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Test</title>
 <style type="text/css">
  body {
   margin: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
  }
  canvas {
   margin: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event listeners should be added outside of your game loop.

Currently you are adding an extra listener for each keypress on every frame, meaning that on the first frame you will move `dx * 1` for a keypress, but on frame 100 you will move `dx * 100` for a single keypress.

This is also why your `dx` value had to be so low - I've increased it in the sample below, but you can adjust it as needed.

```js
//variables
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var draw = canvas.getContext("2d");
var characterx = 20;
var charactery = window.innerHeight - 60;
var dx = 3.0;
var dy = 3.0;

//canvas size
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

//key evevnts
window.addEventListener("keydown",function(event) {
 if(event.keyCode == 39) {
  characterx  += dx;
 }
});
window.addEventListener("keydown",function(event) {
 if(event.keyCode == 37) {
  characterx  -= dx;
 }  
});

//main game function
function run() {

 //loops the function
 requestAnimationFrame(run);

 //clears the screen
 draw.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

 //draws the ground
 draw.beginPath();
 draw.fillStyle = "#823819";
 draw.fillRect(0, canvas.height - 20, canvas.width, 20);
 draw.fill();
 draw.closePath();

 //draws the main character
 draw.beginPath();
 draw.fillStyle = "#128522";
 draw.fillRect(characterx, charactery, 40, 40);
 draw.fill();
 draw.closePath();

};
run();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Test</title>
 <style type="text/css">
  body {
   margin: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
  }
  canvas {
   margin: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```